# Can't subscribe to channel after granting does succeed

Tags: javascript, php, publish-subscribe, pubnub

This is what I do in PHP:

```
$pubnub = new Pubnub(array(
  'subscribe_key' => '<SUBSCRIBE_KEY>',
  'publish_key' => '<PUBLISH_KEY>',
  'secret_key' => '<SECRET_KEY>',
  'uuid' => $uuid,
));
$grants = $pubnub->grant(true, true, $channel, $auth_key, 0);
```

That works. I get a 200 response with my auth key and the correct accesses.

Then I do this in JS:

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
  auth_key: settings.auth_key,
  subscribe_key: settings.subscribe_key,
  publish_key: settings.publish_key,
  uuid: settings.uuid,
});

pubnub.subscribe({
  channel: settings.channel,
  // auth_key: settings.auth_key,
  // uuid: settings.uuid,
  presence: function(m) {
    console.log('presence', m);
  },
  message: function(m) {
    console.log('message', m);
  }
});
```

and that spwans about 10 403 errors per second. I've tried including and excluding a bunch of config vars, like `uuid` and `auth_key`, but all I get is very many 403's.

If I include `origin: 'pubsub.pubnub.com'`, the `presence` event is triggered once or twice, but then still a whole bunch of 403's. If I don't include any `origin`, only 403's, no events.

**Doing a `here_now()` in JS works fine, but `uuids` is empty, and `occupancy` is 0**:

```
setInterval(function() {
  pubnub.here_now({channel: settings.channel}, function(rsp) {
    console.log('here_now', rsp);
  });
}, 2000);
```

- Disabling the Acccess Manager in the PubNub admin console 'fixes' it, but obviously I need Access Management
- I think I've followed https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security pretty exactly, but nothing works.
- https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tutorials/access-manager/ doesn't even mention `.subscribe()`, so no idea what that should do.
- The JS URL called for subscribe (10x/sec) is `http://ps9.pubnub.com/subscribe/<SUBSCRIBE_KEY>/<CHANNEL>%2C<CHANNEL>-pnpres/0/0?uuid=<UUID>&auth=<AUTH_KEY>&pnsdk=PubNub-JS-Web%2F3.7.16`

Why does the PHP `grant` work, but not the JS `subscribe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Presence and Access Manager

Anytime you are using [Presence](https://www.pubnub.com/products/presence/) together with [Access Manager](https://www.pubnub.com/products/access-manager/) (included free with all accounts) in PubNub, when you grant permissions to channels, you also need to grant access to those channels' `-pnpres` counterparts if the clients are going to monitor presence (implement the presence callback or enable presence on a channel - depends on the SDK how this is handled).

```
$grants = $pubnub->grant(true, true, 'sports,sports-pnpres', $auth_key, 0);
```

This code example shows how you can grant to multiple channels in one call.

Comment: I found out today from very quick and good PubNub support. The docs mention nothing of the kind =( And it works. Great! I didn't know about the 2-in-1 grant. Great! Optimization already! Thanks

Comment: Yup, that was me;) Cheers!